# css font family code not working for cusotom text

Tags: html, css, font-face

i want to use a custom font for my website but it's not working.

font name "Road_Rage"
link: [road rage font link][1]

[1]:

```css
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'road';
    src: url('https://youssef-habchi.com/Emb/Road-Rage/Road_Rage.woff');
    font-style: normal;
    }
p{
    font-family: 'road';
}
```

```html
<p>  this is your text </p>
```

please help me.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's dev tools console? You may be hitting a CORS (cross origin) problem.

Comment: no, no errors jsut its not working.. can it be done by google drive? i want to use it on live stream .. in streamlabs

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you running into a cross origin (CORS) problem.

I get this:
[image]

if I run this code from my server - ie the font file is on the same domain:

```
<style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'road';
    src: url('Road_Rage.woff');
    font-style: normal;
    }
p{
    font-family: 'road';
}
</style>
<p>  this is your text </p
```

> 

But I get it in Times New Roman (my default) if I try to serve the font from your given url.

Answer (score 0):

Use True Type Font(TTF)

https://www.dafont.com/road-rage.font

Hope this helps